# How can i know that, what HAL's are to be added in manifest and matrix files for VINTF

Tags: android, android-source, hal

For VINTF(which is part of project treble), we need to add HAL and its version,transport type e.t.c in the manifest and matrix files. How can i know that what HAL's are to be added  to device_manifest.xml, device_compatibility_matrix.xml, framework_manifest.xml and framework_compatibility_matrix.xml.

Answer (score 0):

All the interfaces you need should be added to the *device_manifest* and *device_framework_compatibility_matrix*. They should be the same and just the parent tag is different.